# How to find the maximum and minimum numbers in a dynamic array through a button event

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to get buttons btnMaximum and btnMinimum to display the correct Max and Min numbers to a label. Each button is a separate button and when clicked will display either the max or min number.

I've got the array going but I dont know the proper functions for finding a Max and a Min.

Here is what I have so far:

```
Public Class Form1

Private Sub btnGenerate_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnGenerate.Click
    Dim intNumbers(-1) As Integer
    Dim intCounter As Integer
    ReDim intNumbers(14)

    For intCounter = 0 To intNumbers.Length - 1
        intNumbers(intCounter) = Int((100 - 1 + 1) * Rnd()) + 1
        Me.lstNumbers.Items.Add(intNumbers(intCounter))
    Next
    ReDim Preserve intNumbers(14)
    lstNumbers.Items.Clear()
    For intCounter = 0 To intNumbers.Length - 1
        Me.lstNumbers.Items.Add(intNumbers(intCounter))
    Next


End Sub

Private Sub btnMaximum_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnMaximum.Click


End Sub

Private Sub btnMinimum_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnMinimum.Click

End Sub
End Class
```

I would really appreciate the help.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.min%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, you will need to move the declaration of your integer array outside of the click event for `btnGenerate`. This will allow you to access the array itself outside of that particular function (IE: inside your min and max button functions).

Arrays have two handy functions, `Min` and `Max`.

```
Dim intNumbers() As Integer = New Integer() {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
Dim intMin As Integer = intNumbers.Min          'will contain value 0
Dim intMax As Integer = intNumbers.Max          'will contain value 5
```